# Don't move all of the faces

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hey

I only want the face between the red lines in the picture to be adjusted, so that the edges, here marked red, end up where the blue drawn lines are.
Moving the selected face with <kbd>G</kbd> did not give me the wanted result.

[image]

Here I first extruded the face (selected in the first picture) with <kbd>E</kbd> (instead of moving it), but I don't want those edges which I marked blue.

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are trying to extrude the face? This can be done by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> with the face selected.

To delete those added lines, there are two ways to go about doing so.

Method 1) In edit mode, press <kbd>2</kbd> to enter edge select mode. Select the unwanted edges, press <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Dissolve Edges*.

Method 2) In edit mode, press <kbd>3</kbd> to enter face select mode. Select the faces you want to join together, press <kbd>F</kbd> and those faces should be joined together.

Comment: Yes I hvae updated my question maybe you know it also?

Comment: Yup, added it to the answer.

Comment: If I may, you may want to follow a complete beginner's tutorial series so that you can get a general sense of direction around Blender before diving into your own project (because you're going to have many more questions by the end lol). I've found the donut tutorial series by BlenderGuru to be a big help for me when I was just starting (found here www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U).

Comment: Thank you so much for the tipp.

Answer (score 3):

For the updated question, i made a new short visual showing the way to get rid of the edges you are left with after using <kbd>E</kbd> on the face that you moved along the normal already in the first picture. Though keep in mind that getting rid of those ends up generating n-gons on the sides, as the edges from below still need the vertices to connect, resulting in 5 vertices. Never the less, you asked how to get rid of the edges.

Solution: Dissolve edges (can be found in the right-click (context) menu once edges are selected.

Here a visual explanation for showing the before and after:
[image: dissolved edges visual explanation]

Considering the comments you left i have to tell you though, that there is no one click solution for the result you want. Extruding with <kbd>E</kbd> and then "dissolving" the edges is already very fast.

Comment: I think my question was not so clear I have updated now maybe you know now what I mean, but thanks for you idea.

Comment: Yes now it worked. Thank you. but I still don't quite understand why you can't do it directly without lines. Even if I delete the part, it also deletes things I didn't select but that's another question :-D.

Comment: And you have suggested me and edit right? so it worked out that I accepted your proposal because I don't see any change?

Comment: Not delete, dissolve, which means the edges will be removed and the faces previously split by them will be fused. Deleting a face will also remove the vertices if you do not explicitly chose to only delete the face. And about the edit, yes, i did after i read your comments and figured out the situation behind the first and then second picture. The edit was purely to prevent misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see red lines on blue ones without moving the orange plane, I believe there is a way:

1. Subdivide edges on both sides to make new points on these sides.
2. Enable vertex snap, take these new points and move them, locked by green axis, to make new points stand strictly above old ones.
3. Cut the faces with the Knife (vertex snap enabled).

---

### [image: Pic1]

4. Delete new faces you've got to get the empty space.

---

### [image: Pic2]

5. Select 4 points at potential places for faces and make new faces with F.

---

### [image: Pic3]

Hope I understood you right and it helps! Sorry about small details, English is not my native language. There are already many articles about subdividing, snapping, using knife an so on ^^)

Comment: Thats a good idea but I want it from the very beginning. I updated my question, maybe you know what I mean.